# Using comma and break have an error in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, break

i have a question about break in for loop.

I know 'comma' can make code using no semicolon.

Most of codes are going well, but 'break' doesn't meet this rule.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        puts("hello"),break;

return 0;
}
```

In this code, break have an error "Expression expected" and i don't know why..

Is there any problem? :(

Comment: Well, the `,` operator does expect expression. You do not give one afterwards. What is unclear about the error?

Comment: interesting, i havent code c for long, it seems `keyword` cant be used with `,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma operator needs the operands to be expressions, i.e. something that evaluates to a value. `break`, `continue` etc. are not expressions, instead they are statements which do not evaluate to a value. That's why they can't be used with comma operator.

The error is perfectly clear in the message "Expression expected".

Comment: Thank you, i believed, 'break' is an expression.. until now. Have a good day.

Comment: @SEONGWOOCHAE What value should `break` be evaluated to? If it has no value, it is no expression.